# Redirect A record to Apigateway custom domain in AWS Route53

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I changed my domain NS records (in Digitalocean) to Route 53 NS records and also set A record to api gateway as alias but I couldn't reach to website.

shorty I did:

- create a Lambda function
- add an Api gateway to Lambda
- deploy it to Stage
- generate SSL cert
- add my domain in Custom domain panel and set endpoint type to Edge
- configure API mappings
- Add Hosted zone for doamin in Route53
- Add NS records that gived by Route53 to Digitalocean
- add A record as alias to apigateway (it shown as API Gateway domain name: xxx.cloudfront.net)

I checked A record in https://dnschecker.org/ and figured out that A record not reachable in some places such as some locations in Europe and America but also I couldn't reach to website from Europe and America.

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh ok, I figured out why this happening.

If you might use sub domain as primary domain you should define NS records under primary domain not separately in Digitalocean (also in another platforms).